# Gtk-Gdk Pixmap in Pygobject python

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, pygobject, pixmap

I'm porting a code from PyGtk to PyGI(PyGObject). There is my code:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk','2.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, GObject
w, h = 100,100
# pixmap = gtk.gdk.Pixmap(None, w, h, 1)
pixmap = Gdk.Pixmap(None, w, h, 1) # I Change to it and get error
ctx = pixmap.cairo_create()
```

My error is:

> GObject.**init**() takes exactly 0 arguments (4 given)

...
And Then I Change "Gdk.Pixmap(None, w, h, 1)" To "Gdk.Pixmap.new(None, w, h, 1)"I get this error:

> TypeError: Argument 0 does not allow None as a value

ThankYou :)

Comment: Number one problem is that you are using Gtk2 with introspection. Use `gi.require_version('Gtk','3.0')` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gi` stands for GObject-introspection. This feature only appeared with GTK+ 3, and allowed dynamic bindings, as opposed to static bindings like pyGTK. It seems however that there's a compatibility layer with GTK+ 2 (`pygtkcompat`), but I know no project using that.

Please read this article that gives hints about how to port from pyGTK to pyGObject:
https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/PyGObject/IntrospectionPorting

One of the migration steps is to use the [pygi-convert.sh](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/pygobject/blob/master/tools/pygi-convert.sh) script to update your code and do a part of the migration for you.

Comment: There isn't any "Pixmap" word in pygi-convert.sh(with pygi-convert.sh I get error too). and I added ".new" after "Gdk.Pixmap" but I get error too. I Think in C Programming work gdk_pixmap_new(NULL,w,h,1)

Comment: It would probably be in `GdkPixbuf` and not `Gdk` itself but in Gtk 3 you have to change the `Pixmap` code anyway. Have a look at " Replace GdkPixmap by cairo surfaces" in the [migration guide](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch26s02.html).